# Overriding does not work on virtual method in ASP.net Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

```
namespace ProjectA.Controllers
public partial class CustomerController : Controller
{
 public virtual IActionResult Index()
 {
  ...Some code here
 }

 public virtual IActionResult Login()
 {
  ...Some code here
 }
}


namespace ProjectB.Controllers
public partial class CustomerController : ProjectA.Controllers.CustomerController
{
 public override IActionResult Login()
 {
  ...Some code here
 }
}
```

When I try to override as above it gives me below error

> AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. 
>   The following actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied: 
>   ProjectA.Controllers.CustomerController.Index (ProjectA) 
>   ProjectB.Controllers.CustomerController.Index (ProjectB)

Though there is no Index action in ProjectB. When I change the name of the conroller of ProjectB as:

```
namespace ProjectB.Controllers
public partial class CustomCustomerController : ProjectA.Controllers.CustomerController
{
 public override IActionResult Login()
 {
  ...Some code here
 }
}
```

**AmbiguousActionException** is gone but still the override doesnt work. I dont get call in overriden action.
**Is it like .Net core doesnt support overriding any more because it works like charm without .net core with the same name of controllers.**
Please help..

Answer (score 1):

As you have both class name as “CustomerController”. And both may have using default routing. So for both controllers url should be same as `/{controller}/{action}`.

So for same url there will be 2 actions available for each controllers. That is why you are getting

> “AmbiguousActionException” exception.

When you change your child controller to “CustomCustomerController” then url will be changed for both controllers so no such ambiguity happen so it worked.

As you said override not working. In this case you have to use url as “/CustomCustomer/login” then it will go to Login action of CustomCustomerController.

**EDIT 1**

You can update your code as below and it should work fine. Create your controllers as below:

```
namespace ProjectA.Controllers {
    public partial class CustomerController : Controller
    {
        public virtual IActionResult Index()
        {
            ...Some code here
        }

        public virtual IActionResult Login()
        {
            ...Some code here
        }
    }
}

namespace ProjectB.Controllers {
    public partial class CustomCustomerController : ProjectA.Controllers.CustomerController
    {
        public override IActionResult Login()
        {
            ...Some code here
        }
    }
}
```

And Update `app.UseMvc(routes =>` part into `startup.cs` as below. Add `customer` route before `default` route.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "customer",
        template: "customer/{action}/{id?}",
        defaults: new { controller = "CustomCustomer", action = "Index" });

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for answer but I cannot use url as you said because in View page it is written fixed "Customer/login" and I do not want to move towards customizing view pages as far as it is working from C# code.
This is working fine as I said in MVC5 project but not in .Net MVC Core project..

Comment: @NopAdvance Have you checked routeconfig.cs are exact same in both projects?

Comment: Hi @karan,
Have you ever did this in .net core mvc?

Comment: @NopAdvance, Yes I have worked with core. Have you checked in your core project inside `startup.cs` `app.UseMvc(routes =>` have same `routes.MapRoute(` as on your old project's `RouteConfig.cs`?

Comment: Hi.. thank you. I will check and update that shortly

Comment: This is not working with override. What you provided is only routing solution but we are not looking for that..